# Error getting the row index of a clicked table in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the row number of the table item I'm clicking on. I thought this would work but I'm getting an error saying "Object doesn't support property or method 'parent'" What am I doing wrong? The table is dynamically created so that's why I'm specifying it through a css class.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var table = $('<table></table>');
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".tbl").click(function () { 
            var row = $('<tr></tr>').text($(this).index);
            table.append(row); 
            $('#please').append(table);
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: You aren't calling `.parent()` anywhere in that script above. What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have missed `()`, change this:

```
$(this).index
```

to:

```
$(this).index()
```